# HighCharts Realtime Update x-axis time shift

Tags: highcharts

Please refer to this example
[Real Time HighChart](http://bit.ly/TA3FlP)

I have a similar approach but I am not able to shift the time scale.
can someone please let me know which statement or setting is causing the trend to shift by time.
I am just adding the data but the scale doesn't shift automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have set shift as true in the addPoint function

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint()

Comment: In my case , both x and y values are given. So my addPoint code is, `chart.series[0].addPoint([x,y],false,true );`. But it doesn't seem to work.